# Energy Detection in Presence of Colored Gaussian Noise

Tags: noise, signal-detection, random-process, acoustics, thresholding

Before asking my question, let me introduce the context:

For spectrum sensing based on energy detection, which has been widely studied in presence of AWGN, the optimal detection threshold is computed as:

$$ \lambda = 2~\sigma^2_\omega ~ \sqrt{N}~ (Q^{-1}(P_{fa}) + \sqrt{N})~~~~[1]$$

where $\sigma^2_\omega$ is the noise variance, and $P_{fa}$ is the design false-alarm rate (false-alarm probability).

The detection algorithm works as follows:

We take an interval of $N$ samples of the received signal $x[n] = k~s[n] + \omega[n]$, where $k = 1$ if the signal of interest is present and $k = 0$ otherwise. Here both $s[n]$ and $\omega[n]$ come from zero-mean Gaussian wide-sense stationary processes.

The received energy is then $\Lambda = \sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} |x[n]|^2$, and $\Lambda$ follows a $\chi^2$ distribution.

Now, regarding the presence or not of a signal of interest during the considered interval, it is assumed that $k = 1$ if $\Lambda > \lambda$, and $k = 0$ otherwise.

Of course, equation [1] is not optimal in practical scenarios, since AWGN is just a model not possible in real life. However, let's just accept it as a good approximation for wide-band noise (nearly-uncorrelated noise). After applying an LTI pass-band filter to such a noise, I would obtain Gaussian colored noise (no longer wide-band), and thus uncorrelated samples is no longer a good approximation. As a consequence, not much can be said about the distribution of $\Lambda$, due to the introduced correlation in $x[n]$ after filtering.

**My question is:**
*Is it still justified to assume that the detection threshold $\lambda$ is linearly proportional to the noise variance (after the pass-band filter)?*

**My results in this regard:** A practical application on acoustic signals I am working on suggests a non-linear relation between $\lambda$ and the noise variance, once fixed a false-alarm probability.

I mean, I fix a threshold, then I run the application in absence of a signal of interest, and after a long run I measure the false-alarm rate. By increasing the noise power, for example 10 dB, and then doing the same for the threshold, I obtain a false-alarm rate quite different from the previous run. However, I don't see a proper justification for this behavior other than a non-linear relation between $\lambda$ and the noise variance. And in such a case, I am unable to explain why is this so.

I am using as the receiver a mobile (its microphone), and as the transmitter a speaker.

Should I empirically determine what is this non-linear relation, or is there any theoretical result in this regard that I could use?

Comment: Interesting, could you post an online reference for that formula and its derivation?   I presume you are also band-limiting the "signal" and the LTI is applied to the raw data; not the calculated energy?

Comment: Eq. [1] doesn't come from the exact distribution of the test statistic, which is $\chi^2$. The exact equation is: $P_{fa} = \Gamma(N, \lambda/(2\sigma^2_\omega))/\Gamma(N)$, which is derived from the $\chi^2$ pdf. Eq. [1] is obtained by approximating the pdf to a Gaussian one and then solving for $\lambda$. However, this approximation does not change the linear relation between $\lambda$ and $\sigma^2_\omega$ for a fixed $P_{fa}$. You may find the details, for example, here: http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781493904938-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1447124-p176544244

Comment: Regarding the use of an LTI (band-pass) filter, I apply it to the raw signal. Since I am interested in measuring the false-alarm probability, I am not transmitting any signal of interest, i.e. $k = 0$. The (recorded audio) signal is simply the acoustic noise, which is nearly white in the frequency band of interest. I compute the energy after applying such a filter, thus $x[n]$ is no longer white and Eq. [1] is no longer a good approximation.  However, still I expected a linear relation between $\lambda$ and $\sigma^2_\omega$. I haven't found yet a justification of why it is not the case.

Comment: Just to be double check: your signal chain (in particular the digitization) does preserve the S/N?   5:1 signal (well in your case say standard deviation) is 5 times better than the digitizer; wherever that is.  In addition, your question is about k=0?    What amount of discrepancy are we talking about?  Since your equation [1] obviously says that the ration should be constant, I would assume it's the signal processing that's in error.  Now I am pretty sure that the non-gaussian distribution alters the equation but doesn't matter for your question.

Comment: If I were you I would dump the signal processing numbers along the signal chain and apply the test at each point.  Using a software process to do the squaring for early parts; but examining the data before squaring.  If you want you can post them somewhere and I will look but presumably you wouldn't have any problem.  The purpose is, where do you lose the ratio.  For example:  per thousand samples with three SD's threshold you should 5 hits; as my, admittedly faulty, memory kicks up.  Tedious but you should know where things are falling apart.

Comment: If you want I could do a software model of the ideal case and prove the equation "correct"; but that seems redundant.  The paper is eminently readable, although I think I have another reference (from the 50-60's).

Comment: I would appreciate if you could provide the reference from the 60's. Besides, consider that the threshold does not depend on the S/N ratio. Actually, there is no signal at all when measuring the false-alarm rate. On the other hand, I don't really see why digitizing should be a concern. Could you please provide more details on the subject?

Comment: Part 1: https://www.amazon.com/Detection-Estimation-Modulation-Theory-Part/dp/0470542969   --https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=Xzp7VkuFqXYC&oi=fnd&pg=PR13&dq=van+trees+detection+estimation+and+modulation+theory+pdf&ots=wWKhexoVJK&sig=W0MlAqNJfAIRCqNsEdh2EM99V9Y#v=onepage&q&f=false  --Part 3 online: https://dppattnaik.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/wiley-detection-estimation-and-modulation-theory-part-iii.pdf

Comment: Digitization causes a baseline noise on top of input signal (in your case noise) .  Thus varying the input signal/noise effect will be offset/nonlinear.   In your case I would call the number of false positives with noise input and some threshold your signal.  The books above have thresholding concerns.  As far a general noise theory goes I have several more book on my shelves. For instance, https://www.amazon.com/Electronic-Noise-Andras-Ambrozy/dp/0070011249  which has a chapter "Stochastic Signals  in the Time and Frequency Domain"  Just as humor amazon has " New from $50,000.00" :)

Comment: @rrogers, thank you very much for the references, I will certainly check them. I guess any reference on threshold setting under colored noise will do. The main issue for me is to find a non-empirical method to set the detection threshold. Eq. 1 looks so beautiful for AWGN, and I have tested it before. I expected that for non-white noise (i.e. correlated noise) the ratio between $\lambda$ and $\sigma^2_{\omega}$ would be at least constant as it is for AWGN. I will post my future progress in this regard to have some feedback. Thanks again.

Comment: @rrogers, do you have any experience setting a threshold for signal detection under noise? Do you usually use empirical methods, or have you found theoretical equations that actually work?

Comment: No: most of my experience was in NDIR gas measurement, time division multiplexed and others,  in the 1ppm range for automotive and anesthetic gases.  Yes, the theory and equations work but you have to understand the particular problems involved in order to formulate the models;  i.e. the equations and flow diagrams.  For instance, resistive types of detectors have initial/random offsets and 1/f noise together with high-frequency limits inherent in the implementation.  Of course, every design has to accommodate cost limitations :)  The purpose of all of this is to preserve S/N until evaluation.